# LINQ: Convert DataTable to User Defined Class containing array

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-3.5

I have this object structure

```
public class Product
{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string DisplayName{get;set;}
public Ingredient[] Ingredents{get;set;}
}

public class Ingredient
{
 public int id{get;set;}
 public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

I have the datatable with the below result set

```
    Id | DisplayName  |  IngredientId | IngName
-------------+-------------------------+------------------------
    1  | Prod1         |   1           |  Ing1
    1  | Prod1         |   2           |  Ing2
    1  | Prod1         |   3           |  Ing3
    2  | Prod2         |   1           |  Ing1
    2  | Prod2         |   2           |  Ing2
    3  | Prod3         |   1           |  Ing1
    3  | Prod3         |   2           |  Ing2
```

I need to have LINQ query which would give me list of Products as below:
// pseudo code which describes structure:

```
resultProductList =
{
  new Product() { Id = 1
                , DisplayName = "Prod1"
                , Ingredients = {
                                 new Ingredient{ Id = 1, Name = "Ing1" } 
                                , new Ingredient{ Id = 2, Name = "Ing2" } 
                                , new Ingredient{ Id = 3, Name = "Ing3" } 
                                }
 , new Product() { Id = 2
                , DisplayName = "Prod2"
                , Ingredients = {
                                 new Ingredient{ Id = 1, Name = "Ing1" } 
                                , new Ingredient{ Id = 2, Name = "Ing2" } 
                                }
 , new Product() { Id = 3
                , DisplayName = "Prod3"
                , Ingredients = {
                                 new Ingredient{ Id = 1, Name = "Ing1" } 
                                , new Ingredient{ Id = 2, Name = "Ing2" } 
                                }

}
```

I refered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070153/linq-converting-flat-structure-to-hierarchical) but I am unable to get the solution.

```
List<Product> lstContracttype = dsGetProducts.Tables[0]
                                      .AsEnumerable()
                                      .Select(x => new Product
                                      {
                                          Id= Convert.ToInt32(x[0]),
                                          DisplayName= Convert.ToString(x[1])
                                      })
                                      .GroupBy(y => y.id).ToList();
```

Could anyone please suggest how could I write LINQ query for get this result?

**UPDATE:**
I added one more sub-class and added it to main Product class. See below:

```
public class Product
    {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string DisplayName{get;set;}
    public Ingredient[] Ingredents{get;set;}
    public Price MyPrice{get;set;}
    }
public class Price
{
    public int min {get;set;}
    public int max {get;set;}
    public int defaultPrice {get;set;}
}
```

I modified the LINQ query as follows and am getting the results.
My question is in below LINQ query, should I write `.First<Price>` or `.FirstOrDefault<Price>`? 
Is this proper way to handle this condition or is there any other way?

```
var lstProducts = dsGetProducts.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Cast<DataRow>()
                  .GroupBy(r => new { Id = r["Id"], 
                                      DisplayName = r["DisplayName"], 
                                      priceMax = r["priceMax"],
                                      priceMin = r["priceMin"],
                                      priceDefault = r["priceDefault"]
                                    })
                  .Select(g => new Product()
                  {
                     Id = (int)g.Key.Id,
                     DisplayName = (string)g.Key.DisplayName,
                     Ingredients = g.Select(r => new Ingredient()
                     {
                        id = (int)r["IngredientId"],
                        Name = (string)r["IngName"]
                     }).ToArray(),
                     MyPrice =  g.Select(r => new Price()
                     {
                        min= (int)r["minPrice"],
                        max= (int)r["maxPrice"],
                        defaultPrice= (int)r["priceDefault"],
                     }).FirstOrDefault<Price>()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *group* and then *project*:

```
dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .GroupBy(r => new { Id = r["Id"], DisplayName = r["DisplayName"] })
    .Select(g => new Product()
    {
        Id = (int)g.Key.Id,
        DisplayName = (string)g.Key.DisplayName,
        Ingredients = g.Select(r => new Ingredient()
        {
            id = (int)r["IngredientId"],
            Name = (string)r["IngName"]
        }).ToArray()
    });
```

You need the `Cast<DataRow>`. `DataTable` has been around since .NET 1.1, where generics did not exist. The enumerator therefore yields `object` instances.

Taking comments into account, there is another option you can use, provided you've got .NET Framework 3.5 installed, using the `Field<T>` extension method in `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`. Be sure to add a reference to the assembly:

```
dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .GroupBy(r => new { Id = r.Field<int>("Id"), DisplayName = r.Field<string>("DisplayName") })
    .Select(g => new Product()
    {
        Id = g.Key.Id,
        DisplayName = g.Key.DisplayName,
        Ingredients = g.Select(r => new Ingredient()
        {
            id = r.Field<int>("IngredientId"),
            Name = r.Field<string>("IngName")
        }).ToArray()
    });
```

Comment: I am unable to find dsGetProducts.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Rows where dsGetProducts is DataSet

Comment: @MrudangVora Just use `dsGetProducts.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()` instead of `dsGetProducts.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Rows`

Comment: `dsGetProducts.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()` is already a collection of your typed rows. You can go straight to `Cast<YourTypedRow>`. `Rows` is the collection of untyped rows.

Comment: Since .NET 4.0 there's a new assembly (`System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll`) which provides among others the  `AsEnumerable()` extension method for `DataTable` so you don't need `Rows.OfType<DataRow>` or `Rows.Cast<DataRow>`. Also, the new `Field<T>` extension method allows you to access fields in a typed, safe manner (without manually casting/DBNull checks). You should use them in your code because as it is now, it will not compile (the values accessed via the indexer are all of type `object`).

Comment: @DominicKexel OK, thank you for the remark. I added some casts, but I agree that it's still a little fragile. It'd be great if you could post an example with `Field<T>`, as I haven't used it yet.

Comment: @DominicKexel: I am using .net 3.5.and tried to look for Field<T>. It is present but am unable to figure out how can I write multiple fields in GroupBy.
Can I write something like dsGetProducts.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => (r.Field<int>("Id"), r.Fields<string>("DisplayName"))?

Comment: @MrudangVora You'll have to use a `Tuple` like `GroupBy(r => Tuple.Create(r.Field<int>("Id"), r.Fields<string>("DisplayName")))` or use an anonymous type like Matthias does in his answer.

Comment: Just to spam this answer with more comments: `DataSetExtensions` are available since .NET 3.5, not .NET 4.0. Instead of `(int)r["IngredientId"]`, you can use `r.Field<int>("IngredientId")`. While that don't seem to do much, it really shines with nullable database fields since it automatically converts `DBNull` values to `null` (for value types, you can use e.g. `Field<int?>("someNullablevalue")`).

Comment: @DominicKexel: Tuple is available only in .NET 4.0 not 3.5 :( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @DominicKexel: I updated my question and I am getting the expected results. Thanks for your help.
Just wanted to know whether the approach is correct. Could you please let me know the same?